# How to display jFree chart for a table of values vs Time taken

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I was trying to display values like Heartrate,blood pressure vs time taken.
How can I display like a bar graph using JFree chart??
Getting a `NullPointerException` in my for loop

```
private CategoryDataset createDataset(VitalSignDirectory vitalSignDirectory) {
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

    for(VitalSign v : patient.getVitalSignDirectory().getVitalSignList()) {
        String heartRate = String.valueOf(v.getHeartRate());


        dataset.addValue(v.getRespRate(), heartRate, heartRate);
    }
    return dataset;
}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace. What is `patient`? Make sure it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [link](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=23991) showing how to create a time/value bar graphs.

The key point being that data should be added as

```
TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Series 1", Month.class);
s1.add(new Month(1, 2001), 142);
s1.add(new Month(2, 2001), 181);
```